# How to get Progress dialogue when downloading data from internet in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

> Hi,
>
> How to get progress dialogue when the application is fetching data
>   from web in android?

Comment: here you can see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3028306/626481

Comment: or http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'AsyncTask' process the download. and it has a method `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`. in this method you can diaplay the progress

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SimpleWebGrab extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        grabURL("http://android.com");
    }

    public void grabURL(String url) {
        new GrabURL().execute(url);
    }

    private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SimpleWebGrab.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
            if (Error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleWebGrab.this, Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleWebGrab.this, "Source: " + Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```